# Save email copy when sending to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some issues with Outlook not showing emails correctly. With this in mind I'm trying to create that link that usually says "click if you can't see this email properly" or something like that. To achieve that I need to store all emails that are sent to users, in a html file that when opened you see the exact same thing as the original email.

The gem letter_opener does something like this, but it's not meant to be used on production. Is there a way to achieve what this gem does, by storing all emails to a folder and also deliver them to users?

I have tried to save email messages to a html file but had no success, the main content was there, but styles were completely messed up, the file generated by letter_opener is perfect.

this is some of what I tried to do

```
email = mail to: @voucher.recipient.email,
     cc: ENV['NOREPLY_EMAIL'],
     bcc: bcc,
     subject: "Voucher #{voucher&.order_item&.product&.title}"

File.open('filename.html', 'wb') {|f| f.write(email.html_part.body.encoded) }
```

Comment: You can use an email service that provide this function, such as MailChimp.

Comment: When you click the link "click here if you can't see properly" you are redirected to a web page. I guess you can create a controller and different views for the different email campaigns you send to your users. In this view, you just have to replicate what there is in your email... There is probably some posts out there  on how to do so in an orderly manner..